# AWS Cloud Search replace indexes with new one

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch, aws-php-sdk

I'm using AWS PHP API to do some stuff with AWS Cloud Search. Right now I have static indexes. But I need to replace them dynamically.

E.g. current indexes are:

```
name | date | content
```

and I want to replace them with

```
time | description | username
```

How can I do it? How to delete all indexes/replace them with new indexes. Also how long re-indexing will take?

I assume I can cache indexes locally and than with `deleteIndexField` than do `defineIndexField`, but I don't think it's efficient way to do that. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

There's no batch-delete or batch-create for indexes in most Cloudsearch APIs.  you'll have to delete and create each index individually.  Re-indexing in my experience usually takes 25-45 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You delete the old fields and creates new fields or edit name index into panel control into AWS Console, after this re-index.